# Quicklook/QLPreviewController shows a blank page instead of pdf in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction, quicklook

I searched longtime but did'n get the exact solution for this!
QLPreviewController not opening the documents,it showing only blank page.

Comment: you should show your code that how you are doing that! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307326/quicklook-qlpreviewcontroller-shows-a-blank-page-instead-of-pdf-on-ios-8-but-wor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307326/quicklook-qlpreviewcontroller-shows-a-blank-page-instead-of-pdf-on-ios-8-but-wor)

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a known issue in iOS 8 Beta 5.

See the URL under QuickLook https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/

Comment: This response it's not according with the question. also it just a copy and paste from another question's answer.